# Getting the Location of Endpoints on the Canvas in JsPlumb for FlowChart Connector

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

Is there any way to get the location of endpoint on the canvas of a flowchart connector in jsPlumb...
I ld also like to get the location of the bends when a flowchart connector is drawn from one element to another...

Can anybody help me out?

Or is there any other JS API with this feature?